# How can I play a song on a loop using WMPLib ? (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, windows-media-player, wmplib

I'm developing a Windows Forms app in C# using VS 2019. I'm using the WMPLib, I created a WindowsMediaPlayer:

```
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        player.URL = "song.wav";
        player.controls.play();
```

When the song ends it doesn't restart. I need to play this song on a loop, how can I do this??

Comment: [IWMPSettings::setMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/wmplibiwmpsettings-iwmpsettings-setmode--vb-and-c)